# chrome driver : disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tfs, tfsbuild

I am working with c# selenium.
I am getting error with chrome driver as :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 
(9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (102)
```

Now I tried updating the chrome browser version to 2.33 and its working fine on my local machine.
But I am getting this error my server where I am executing this tests on schedule basis.

I am using TFS to deploy tests on the server and to run the tests.

the same project is working on my local machine but I am getting this error on server for the

```
 driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

line for all the tests.

I check out same project from TFS on my colleagues machine and tried executing there its was working fine.

I tried updating driver to 2.33 even tried downgrading the driver to 2.32 and executed multiple time but its not working.

I am using MS build to build the automation project and deploy it on server as well.

Comment: Make sure that the driver is 2.33 (the one in your exception is 2.32) and try to disable the GPU with the switch `--disable-gpu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  it works well on your local machine，but got error when you run the tests on the server.

First make sure your server environment are the same with your local machine such as chrome browser version is 2.33 and the driver is also 2.33.

According to this code `driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`  line.

Please make sure that you give enough time for the window to load before you declare this statement.

If you are finding any element to input some data then provide reasonable delay between this and the input statement.

Answer (score 1):

When I am using Python 3, facing the same error, in my situation, I did not close the chrome process after using it. So you should check the chrome process properly closed after using it.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 2499
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.75)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I have faced the same problem today, It get resolved by using updated chrome driver pack **2.33**.